# Azure Web App on Linux: "Error: Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080" - when using: "start": "pm2 start server.js"

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

My App Service Linux instance crashes if my node app is using the start script: `"start": "pm2 start server.js"`:

```
2019-04-15 11:36:34.432 ERROR - Container crime-digest__6ea5_0 for site crime-digest__6ea5 has exited, failing site start
2019-04-15 11:36:34.489 ERROR - Container crime-digest__6ea5_0 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
```

Container logs have nothing but the above error. If I use just: `"start": "node server.js",` the app starts just fine.

I understand that if the container doesn't respond via 8080 the container gets stopped, but I'm having `process.env.PORT` set as the port of my server so I can't figure out why the pm2 start script crashes the container.

I have a feeling that `process.env.PORT` is undefined if using the above start script because of some mixup in the process but can't find any way to debug it because **after the container crashes I'm unable to ssh into it any more** to inspect it.

Comment: Creating an http server in my code instead of an https solved this issue for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same issue. When I changed the code in my server.js file to the below it succesfully ran:

```
const port = process.env.port || 8080;
```

After redeploying to Azure it is now working.

Comment: I know this is almost 2 years old but it helped me solve my problem today thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Are we trying to ping on PORT 8080? The problem here is that port 8080 is not exposed, so when we attempt to ping the container, we aren't pinging on a port on which the container is listening.

There are a couple of ways to resolve this.

1. Use the EXPOSE instruction in your Dockerfile to expose port 8080.
2. Use the WEBSITES_PORT app setting with a value of "8080" to expose that port.

You can refer the below mentioned articles:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/09/08/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/

Comment: Can we disabled the ping process?

Comment: I already did this, still not luck, got same message. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when working on Deploying  a Rails Application to Azure Web App for Containers

When I deploy the app to Azure, I will get the error below:

```
2021-07-29T10:29:05.571Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container devopsapptest_0_2eeeb139 for site devopsapptest
2021-07-29T10:29:07.733Z ERROR - Container devopsapptest_0_2eeeb139 for site devopsapptest has exited, failing site start
2021-07-29T10:29:07.737Z ERROR - Container devopsapptest_0_2eeeb139 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

By default, App Service assumes your custom container is listening on port `80`, however, my application was listening to requests on port `3000`, which led to the error.

If your container listens to a different port, set the `WEBSITES_PORT` app setting in your App Service app. That is a `WEBSITES_PORT` as one of your app settings with the port your app is listening to. In my case, it was `3000`.

You can set it in Azure CLI:

```
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --settings WEBSITES_PORT=8000
```

In Azure PowerShell:

```
Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Name <app-name> -AppSettings @{"WEBSITES_PORT"="8000"}
```

**Note**: App Service currently allows your container to expose only one port for HTTP requests.

You may desire to also add the `EXPOSE your-port` command to the `Dockerfile` of your project. However, for my project, I did not have to add the `EXPOSE your-port` command, and it worked fine for me.

**Note**: Endeavour to redeploy the application preferably from your CICD pipeline again after this change to refresh the application.

**Resources**: [Configure a custom container for Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-port-number).

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the application setting PORT with the value of whatever port your app is listening on.

Ref: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34451

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue but finally found the answer. The problem on my side was that I was building the image using my MacBook M2 Max which runs on different architecture. Changing the build command to something like this

```
docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t next-portfolio:latest .
```

has solved the issue. I was trying to deploy to Azure using AppService with Docker using Docker hub. After this all the port issue has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible that your application is taking some time to respond, docker container on azure web service wait for 230 secs to get a reply and if it crosses that time limit it will simply halt and give "container didn't respond to HTTP pings ...", u can increase this time limit by making changes to your application setting under "configuration" blade in azure app service by adding
WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT to 420 (as needed).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue. If nothing helps, make sure your web-app returns a "Not Found (404)" response for not implemented API endpoints.

Courtesy of this answer on server fault:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1003418/azure-docker-app-error-site-did-not-start-within-expected-time-limit-and-co

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by changing the HTTPS initiate server command to HTTP. I didn't know that Microsoft already offer this service.

FROM:

`var server = https.createServer(app).listen(port, ()=>{console.log('server is runing at port ' + port) });`

TO:

`var server = http .createServer(app) .listen(port, ()=>{ console.log('server is runing at port ' + port) });`

Answer (score 0):

By me the issue was that the application was running on 127.0.0.1 and not on 0.0.0.0

A solution for a Flask service:

In Azure portal configuration:
Set the environment variable:

> WEBSITES_PORT  8000

And add a Startup Command:

> flask run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8000

You might need to run a new deployment, a restart didn't change the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same error. For me the problem was that I build the container locally on my Mac (silicon CPU) and then pushed it to Azure, and Azure didn't like the build.

When I instead let Azure build it, it worked. I run this command to make Azure build the container:

```
az acr build --image <SAVE_PATH_ON_CONTAINER_REGISTRY> --registry <YOUR_CONTAINER_REGISTRY> --file Dockerfile .
```

Example:

```
az acr build --image sample/hello-world:v1 \
  --registry mycontainerregistry008 \
  --file Dockerfile .
```