# Deploy Flask WebApp on Microsoft Azure

Tags: python, azure, tensorflow, flask, web-deployment

I am new to web development and am currently trying to deploy a Flask Web Application on Microsoft Azure. I do so from a local Git repository as I am using tensorflow models that have a size of almost 600MB altogether which I cannot upload on GitHub.

The application works locally and I can successfully deploy it in Microsoft Azure (according to the CMD). However, visiting the URL gives a '503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'. What does that mean?

Can someone explain to me how I need to structure my application to make it work properly. I know that I need a startup.txt file to tell Azure where to find my main.py file to start the Flask app. I also have a requirements.txt file with all the dependencies. What am I missing?

Any help / feedback is very much appreciated!
All the best,
snowe

My current app structure:

```
.git
static
templates
models
utils (some python functions)
main.py
requirements.txt
startup.txt (with: gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 main:app)
```

Comment: it is correctly deployed, you need to see what error you are facing in logs or deploy it manually on azure

Comment: Hi sahasrara62 :) I redeployed everything and now I don't get any errors when I open the URL. I only get the default page. When I open the 'Git clone url' it says 'No route registered for '/<appname>.git'. Does that mean anything? And what do you mean with deploy manually?

Comment: i don't have hand on experience with ci cd process, but in azure you can upload code in azure repo and create a ci cd process to deploy the system, you can deploy them in pipline in azure

Comment: Now I get:
`
ERROR - Container <appname> for site <appname> has exited, failing site start
ERROR - Container <appname> didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start
`
what does that mean?
in my flask main.py file, which port do I have to specify and which host?

Comment: [expose export error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688600/azure-web-app-on-linux-error-container-didnt-respond-to-http-pings-on-port) please go through this, regarding [deploying flask app in azure](https://medium.com/@nikovrdoljak/deploy-your-flask-app-on-azure-in-3-easy-steps-b2fe388a589e) try with a sample project and see how u can scale it to you current project :)

Comment: thank you, I will try :)

Comment: I managed to make it work with your advice sahasrara62, thank you! I had to downscale my application and its resources but at least I got a working pipeline :)

Comment: cool, good to know it's working :)

Comment: I hope u r doing well and deployed ur project in cloud, [little more help](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-deploy-ml-models-using-flask-gunicorn-nginx-docker-9b32055b3d0) if you still stuck somewhere